# Shallow copy for arraylist

Tags: java, class, arraylist, copy, shallow-copy

Hi i'm using the clone() method to copy the reference of my arraylist like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cloning {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
v.add(new Int(i));
System.out.println("v: " + v);
ArrayList v2 = (ArrayList)v.clone();
for(int i=0;i<v2.size();i++ )
((Int)v2.get(i)).increment();
System.out.println("v: " + v);
}
}
```

The output is

```
v: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
v: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Otherwise if i make this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cloning {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
v.add(new Int(i));
System.out.println("v: " + v);
ArrayList v2 = v;
for(int i=0;i<v2.size();i++ )
((Int)v2.get(i)).increment();
System.out.println("v: " + v);
}
}
```

The output is the same. So my question is, if i use the clone() method for arraylist or i do ArrayList v2 = v; is the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

> The output is the same. So my question is, if i use the clone() method for arraylist or i do ArrayList v2 = v; is the same thing?

It isn't:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> b = makeCopy(a);
a.add("Hello");
System.out.println(b);
```

This code will print `[]` (as in, a blank list with nothing in it), if `makeCopy` is:

```
public List<String> makeCopy(List<String> in) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(in); // or .clone(), same thing.
}
```

But it'll print `[Hello]` if makeCopy is just `return in;` (the equivalent of `List<String> b = a;`.

It's not the components - those aren't cloned (hence, 'shallow'). It is the list *itself*. An actual clone means that there are 2 list objects, and thus you can modify one list without modifying the other. The list objects just contain references (pointers), and shallow cloning the list doesn't clone those objects.

With `List<String> b = a` you just have 2 references to a single list. Given that there is just the one list, if you modify a list (either `a.add()` or `b.add()`, well, there's only one list, so, that's the one you are changing, and a and b reflect the change identically:

```
b = a;
System.out.println(a.size()); // prints 1
b.add("Goodbye");
System.out.println(a.size()); // prints 2
```

Having `a` remain a list of size 1? That requires cloning the list.